# Get current logged in user id

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to get current logged in user id and pass it to the view. Users login with username and password.
spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/panel/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" />
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/" />

        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.terafast.tem.AuthSuccessHandler" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select u1.username, u2.role from users u1, user_roles u2 where u1.role_id = u2.role_id and u1.username =?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayVacationRequestPage(Model model) {
    Vacation vacation = new Vacation();
    model.addAttribute("vacation", vacation);

    return "panel/createRequest";
}
```

Could someone explain how can I do that?

Comment: Use the security namespace for that how to use it depends on your view technology used.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simply mapping method

```
  @RequestMapping("/user")
  public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
  }
```

If the `/user` mapping is reachable it will return the currently authenticated user. Consider annotating your response with `@ResponseBody`, depending on how you have set up your controller and how you plan to use it in your view.

For passing a particular property you can do something like

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/username", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String printUser(ModelMap model, Principal user) {
      String name = user.getName(); //get logged in username
      model.addAttribute("username", name);
      return "panel/createRequest";
  }
```

Comment: I want to pass ID of logged in user And pass both vaction Object and Id to my view...